# Vue 3 Apollo Cache Refreshes But Components Don't When I Get Conditionally Data

Tags: vue.js, caching, graphql, apollo, lighthouse

I'm trying to mutate(create) a data. It's created in database. As i look at the cache on the Apollo extension, it's added in the cache as well. But components don't refresh. The data i try to add is not in there. But it happens, when i get conditionally data. If i get all the data. It refreshes normally.

```
userBoards(owner_id: ID! @eq): [Board!] @all
```

This is the conditionally query that when i use, doesn't refresh components.

```
allBoards: [Board!] @all
```

But when i try this one. It works. I just change queries. The loops, codes, updating, everything is same. Let me share them with you;

```
apollo: {
    userBoards: {
        query: UserBoards,
        variables: {
            owner_id: 1
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code that i use to get data.

Let me share with you guys my query:

```
query UserBoards($owner_id: ID!) {
    userBoards(owner_id: $owner_id) {
        id
        title
        color
    }
}
```

---

```
this.$apollo.mutate({
            mutation: BoardAdd,
            variables: {
                title: "Title",
                color: "Color",
                owner_id: 1
            },
            update(store, { data: { boardAdd } }){
                let data = store.readQuery({
                    query: UserBoards,
                    variables: {
                        owner_id: 1
                    }
                });
                let dataCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));
                dataCopy.userBoards.push(boardAdd);
                store.writeQuery({ query: UserBoards, data: dataCopy });
            }
        }).then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        });
```

And this is the code that i use to mutate(create) the data.

And this is the mutation:

```
mutation BoardAdd($title: String!, $color: String!, $owner_id: ID!) {
    boardAdd(input: { title: $title, color: $color, owner_id: $owner_id }) {
        id
        title
        color
    }
}
```

Everything is fine. Mutation works. Just cache doesn't refresh components. That's the problem i'm talking about.

Thank you :)